# Is it possible to recover the text from my polarization-dependent apodization question about CHIME?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Canada's CHIME radio telescope is a unique design which is discussed at some length in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29168/7982). I a comment below the question there I link to a question (presumably of mine) titled [How does Canada's radiotelescope CHIME manage polarization-dependent apodization of the fast f/0.25 optics?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28615/7982) but the link is now broke. I think that suggests the question had zero votes (or at least no up votes) and perhaps little activity so some SE bot deleted it. Not checking my recently deleted questions frequently enough, it eventually moved beyond my personal event horizon.

Is there any way to recover this question or at least the text thereof, perhaps with moderator help? I promise to spell "radio telescope" as two words this time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see it, even though it has been [roomba'ed](/help/roomba) as you thought. If you have a link, you can always see your own deleted posts, and we both have [enough reputation to see all deleted posts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (as long as we have a link to it).

Anyway, the link *is* working for me, so I saved the body of the question as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/0b202f6a10cb9e1774c2b933045027f9) now.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply and help! Hmm... this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdMse.png and now that I look more carefully at that screen (beyond the big "404" I see that it says "for reasons of moderation" which now has me more puzzled. Maybe Github is not the right place to post the text until we find out more about why it was deleted? (I've grabbed the text, thank you!) Since you can see the question, can you double-check the deletion reason; was it in fact roomba'ed like I guessed it was, or is there some other reason given?

Comment: That screenshot shows you're not logged in, which explains why you cannot see the deleted question. The banner says 'automatically deleted by Community', hence I blame Roomba.

Comment: Oh, just a sec, ya this browser does that... YES, it's this stupid browser that makes me re-log in each time I right-click and open a link in a new tab. Yes I can see it now!! @@ It was roomba'ed and I've now given it a reopen vote. Hopefully it will get a few more so I can put a nice bounty on it. *Thanks!*

Comment: update: ha! It was reopened, I added a bounty, and it's been re-roomba'ed again! :-D [Roomba'ed as abandoned question was found, undeleted, bountied, and then was re-roomba'ed all within one day, is this "by design" behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359901/303080)